# Changing const object - no warning? Also, in which case it is UB?

Tags: c, visual-studio, language-lawyer

Why is there no warning in the following code?

```
int deserialize_students(const Student *dest, const int destCapacityMax)
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    int i=0;


    ptr_file =fopen("output.txt","r");
    if (!ptr_file)
        return -1;

    if(destCapacityMax==0)
        return -2;

    while (!feof (ptr_file))
    {  
        fscanf (ptr_file, "%d", &dest[i].id);    // UB?
        fscanf (ptr_file, "%s",  dest[i].name);     
        fscanf (ptr_file, "%d", &dest[i].gender);      
        i++;

        if(i==destCapacityMax)
            return 0;

    }
    fclose(ptr_file);
    return 0;
 }
```

This is how I called it:

```
Student students[5];
deserialize_students(students,5);
```

Also I have following question: is what I did undefined behaviour?
Note:

- I think passing `students` is fine because function expects `const Student*` and I can pass non `const`. Right?
- But when I modify that object in `fscanf`, did I trigger UB? Or it depends whether `students` was declared const or not in the first place(outside that function)?

Comment: You don't get an error/warning because `fscanf` is a variadic function just expects _any_ arguments after the format string and therefore the compiler can't tell. Not sure if it's UB, probably it is.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: compiler can't tell but I have trigerred UB right?

Comment: The answer to the first question is "Yes, you can pass a non-const". As to the second question, **I think** that you did not trigger UB, exactly because you've passed a non-const. As long as it is allocated in a writable memory segment, no harm is done. On the other hand, the C-language standard does not refer to the "physical" access permission of different memory segments, and in addition, the definition of UB is extremely broad. So one might claim that purely by the standard, it is UB.

Comment: @barakmanos: if `students` variable was declared the way it is now, I think it is not UB, if it was declared as `const Student students[5];`-and then passed to the function, then it would be UB, do you agree with this?

Comment: @userq: That's exactly what I wrote in my initial comment. But please read the updated comment - in its current form, like I said, "no harm is done". Nevertheless, purely by the standard, one might claim that it **is** UB. People here on Stack Overflow like using this concept in order to answer just about anything, so I'd expect most of the answers you'll get to tell you that it is UB.

Comment: There is no UB in *this* case but the function signature is broken. It is tasked with modifying/initialising an object, so why does it accept a const pointer to it?

Answer (score 2):

There's no undefined behaviour in your code.

What the caller passed is a mutable object. So it's fine to modify it either directly or by explicit cast:

```
int func(const int *p) {
  int *q = (int*)p;
  *q = 5;
}
```

is fine (probably ill-advised way but legal) as long as the object passed to `func()` is a mutable one.

But if the object passed was `const` qualified then it would have been undefined behaviour. So in your case, it's *not* undefined.

The qualifier `const` is only a contract that the function is not supposed to modify `dest`. It has no bearing on the *actual* mutability of an object. So the modifying a const-qualified invokes UB or not depends whether the object passed to has any such qualifier.

As for the warning, GCC (5.1.1) warns for:

```
int func(const int *p) {
   fscanf(stdin, "%d", p);
}
```

with:

```
warning: writing into constant object (argument 3) [-Wformat=]
```

Probably VS doesn't recognize that `fscanf()` modifies the object. But the C standard only says that it's undefined if you modify a const-qualified object:

*(C11 draft, 6.7.3, 6 type qualifiers)*

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a
>   const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified
>   type, the behavior is undefined.

There's no diagnostic required by the C standard if the code invokes undefined behaviour. In general, you are on your own if your code causes UB and a compiler may not be able to help you in all causes.

Comment: My own understanding of standard is that `int *q = (int*)p;` forces the compiler to accept it and generate the code. But I would be afraid that the compiler used the const declaration in caller to whatever optimisation. Is it guaranteed that it will pass original object, or could it pass a copy for a const using the as-if-rule?

Comment: @SergeBallesta There are two scenarios here: 1) The object is const qualified for the object at its definition. This case is quite simple: any attempt to change it after that by any means is UB. 2) An object is mutable but a function to which it is passed has `const` qualifier for it (OP's example).
Here, the object *is* mutable and so it's well-defined. Re optimization: `const` in function parameter is not meant for optimization (there may be optimizations for case 1 as long as no UB is invoked). Of course, compiler is allowed to perform any sort of optimization while obeying the as-if rule.

Comment: But a compiler can't blindly assume that the object is  immutable because the function parameter has const-qualifier. I read your answer and you seem to be confusing `const` with `restrict` which does require such a promise from the programmer. But `const` doesn't. Would I recommend such as cast? Absolutely not (otherwise, there's no point in using `const` qualifier in function parameters). But I am talking about the legality it. In general, optimization plays no role in defining whether an operation (or construct) would lead to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it is formal UB.

The function `deserialize_students` declares a `const Student *dest` parameter. From there on, `dest[i].id` is a const int, and `&dest[i].id` is a `const int *`.

You get no warning, because `fscanf` is a variadic function, and compiler cannot control constness (even if gcc uses it as a special case) but if you used an temp intermediary variable you would get an error:

```
int id;
fscanf (ptr_file, "%d", &id);
dest[i].id = id;       // here you get an error
```

So you are passing a const pointer to a function that modify the pointee (`fscanf`) and IMHO it is enough to qualify it as formal UB. One could imagine a implementation of a compiler that would pass a pointer to a copy of the value to `fscanf`, since you promised it was const. Or that would have passed a pointer to a copy of the `students` array since `deserialize_students` declares its parameter as const.

Is there a real risk? IMHO no because as you pass a modifiable `dest` to the function, normal compiler implementation will just pass the original address, and will the same pass the address of `dest[i].id` to `fscanf`. So the whole thing will end in correctly modifying the original array. But as already said by Peter, *like all instances of undefined behaviour, one possible result is working like you expect*, so working with all tested compilers is not an insurance for not being undefined behaviour.

NB: as the original array is not const, the object was not *defined* as const, so I am not sure that 6.7.3,§ 6 applies here. But 6.7.3 § 9 still says: *For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the identically qualified version of a compatible type* so `int *` (required by fscanf), and `const int *` (actually passed) are not.

Comment: @userq: barak manos gave a nice summary in its comments: *"no harm is done". Nevertheless, purely by the standard, one might claim that it is UB*. Will it work? Yes - Is it strictly standard conformant? No

Answer (score 0):

The standard is unclear on the matter. From C11 7.21.6.2/12:

> The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> **d** Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the strtol function with the value 10
>   for the base argument. The corresponding argument shall be **a pointer to
>   signed integer**.

Now, you could argue that because it doesn't say "a pointer to non-const signed integer", it actually means that `int *` and `const int *` are both OK.   Or you could argue that they meant pointer to non-const signed integer only.

Note that the definition of vararg passing (7.16) explicitly says that it's undefined to use `va_arg(int *)` to retrieve an argument of type `const int *`.  However, the fscanf function is NOT specified to behave as if `va_arg` had been used. So this is not directly relevant.

---

*Opinion follows:* The entire specification of `printf` and `scanf` are a sloppy mess that is below the usual quality of specification found in the rest of the standard.  There are many other such examples, e.g. according to the exact wording of the standard, `printf("%lx", 1L);` is undefined behaviour whereas `printf("%lx", -1L);` is not undefined behaviour.

In reality implementations made their own decisions about what to do, and nobody wants to touch the standard wording with a barge pole.  So I would say there is not really a correct answer to this question.